# Getting the spacebar to resume the animation in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to use the spacebar to resume an animation after using the 
stop(); code. What would I use to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

I'd add `EventListener` for `KEY_UP` and when it's triggered check if it's space. If it is, just resume animation.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, handleKeyUp);

private function handleKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
        play();
}
```